Is that part of an Android tablet charger called a connector in a conversation that a mom may say?
I know some computer and programming stuff and I guess that many people in this forum also have computer or programming knowledge. It seems people who know computer might also be interested in language. I remember people who did artificial intelligence also knew English grammar and vocabulary in university.
I have an Android Lenovo tablet. It has a charger. One of its ends plugs into a USB port and the other goes into the tablet.

(source)
I did my research and it seems the metal bits sticking out of the ends are called "connectors".
Would a mom, who doesn't know much computer stuff, say this in a conversation?
-The connector doesn't fit well in my tablet
-The cable doesn't fit well in my tablet
-The charger doesn't fit well in my tablet
Note: the reason I say "fit well" is that:
I also have a tiny fan with a cable that has the same connectors. I can plug the tiny fan's cable into my tablet and it works just fine except that I must not move the cable a lot. The reason is that the connector fits but not 100% fit, so if I move the fan's cable around then I can not charge my tablet.

connectors are part of a cable....think about that for a just a minute. If a cable doesn't work, we don't know what actually doesn't work, the cable or the end (connector).  And mostly, we don't care.  Also, that cable doesn't fit my tablet. Finally, you needn't be an IT expert to know all this. All of us have computers, laptops, tablets and smartphones that require cables or one type or another. Also, no one would say fits well, it either fits or does not. A cable is not a charger, by the way.

In my experience, they either fit or they don't fit, so "fit well" seems odd, agreed.

@Lambie, please read the update to see why I say "fit well", it fits but not 100% because I use a similar cable of another gadget for my tablet. Language is flexible right.

No, fit well does not work. But your new trousers seem to.  cable ends either fit or do not. No language is not flexible here as there is a one-to-one correspondence in this case to the referent's reality. It would be better for you to just accept what both TimR and I are saying.

My 'mom' was writing computer programs for Unix in the early 1970s.

@MichaelHarvey Yes, you are excellent at oneupmanship. And I was working on a digital Vax. So what? Here's one for you:  I'm off to sip my Pinot Grigio on my porch overlooking Boston Harbor. Can you beat that? :)

If you've never had a cable connector that only works sometimes or needs to be held in place or falls out randomly or sometimes needs to a jiggled a bit, then you're probably not very familiar with technology.

@Lambie - I was using my mother's data-processing career to challenge the idea that 'moms' don't (and can't) understand technology, especially if it's IT related.

@StuartF Yes, of course. Then I buy a new cable.

Although this question is weeks old and has an answer, I found it in the review queue, and would suggest altering it. The problem is the hypothetical under-knowledgeable mom. Of course someone who doesn't know much might misuse any term! Perhaps what you mean is "what is a non-specialized term that most non-specialists would recognize for this thing." And yes—"connector" is great for that.

Yes, the "metal bits" on the ends of the cable are connectors. The one on the left is USB-C and the one on the right is USB-A. If either doesn't "fit well" in your mother's computer then either it or the socket in the computer is damaged or worn. Try another cable.

What your mum calls them is down to her and we cannot say how she would describe them.

The part that extends into the connection can be called a plug or male connector.
The part that receives the plug can be called a socket, jack, or female connector.
For wall (mains) connectors, the terms would be, respectively, plug and socket or receptacle.

Image adapted from Precision Camera

wall mains? That's electrical and not the context here. These connectors either work or do not work. No one breaks it down. They just buy a new cable. None of this is something a mother would say to a kid (see the questin). This is only of interest to nerds, geeks and electricity freaks. So, your answer contains correct technical terms but is culturally inaccurate.

@Lambie, "mains" is UK English, therefore in parentheses. Yes, it's additional info. Some people use terms like "gozinta" for "plug", because they lack the vocabulary [the part goes into the other], but it can be useful to know the correct word, for those not adverse to learning.

We say mains in the US too. But that's where the juice comes in from the street to the house ending at the breaker (junction box). There are mains that are electrical and also water mains.

@Lambie - it's like that in the UK, too, with some differences. Under the road in cities and nearby are buried big pipes or cables called 'mains'. My street has a gas main, a water main, and an electricity main. Branch pipes or cables come in to each building via a meter usually. If you plug something electrical into a 230 volt 'socket' you are plugging it into the mains; it runs off/from the mains, not off/from a battery.

@MichaelHarvey Yes, we have water mains, gas mains and electrical mains. Yes, off those are smaller pipes or cables. BUT in houses: we also say mains to refer to these systems even though they connect to the street's mains via smaller pipes. Sockets are in the walls. Sure. Now, can we stop all this off-topic stuff?
